# Send Bitmap via e-mail without saving it on device - Android

Tags: java, android, email, bitmap

I'm creating an android application where I need to send a picture taken by the camera, but for security reasons I cannot have this picture saved in the users device.

Every solution that I found about sending a Bitmap via e-mail seems to archive it on the app's directory and then use it's path to send it.

In my application the image is only used on this very activity (and when sent via e-mail).

Soo... Is there anyway of sending a Bitmap without saving it?

EDIT:
Here is how I'm trying to do this as of right now (it's not working btw).

Calling for the camera:

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Opens camera app
        foto          = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
});
```

Getting the result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //Converts picture to PNG
    if ((requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        thumbnail       = (Bitmap)    data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_comment);
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

        try {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            if (root.canWrite()){
                // We + "/MapTest" to make it storage on a deeper directory for our application
                problemPicture       = new File(getCacheDir(), "problemPicture.png");
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(problemPicture);
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("BROKEN", "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Sending email (foto is set to true right before it):

```
public void sendEmail(){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        if(foto) { //if user attached a pic
            i.setType("image/png");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"sample_mail@gmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Assistencia Tecnica");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(problemPicture));
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, commentText.getText());
            problemPicture.delete();
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Enviando Email..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(StatusActivity.this, "Comunicaçaõ Falhou",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            try {
                // We try to delete the picture
                boolean success = problemPicture.delete();
                if(success) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "File deleted successfully");
                } else {
                    if(problemPicture.isDirectory()) {
                        success = deleteDirectory(problemPicture);
                        if(success) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Directory deleted successfully!");
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Could not delete directory");
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "File could not be deleted");
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // In case we don't find it
                Log.i(TAG, "File not found");
            }

            try {
                deleteFile("problemPicture.png");
            } catch(NullPointerException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Context file not found");
            }
        }
        else {
            i.setType("plane/text");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"sample_email@gmail.com"});
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Assistencia Tecnica");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, commentText.getText());
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Enviando Email..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(StatusActivity.this, "Comunicaçaõ Falhou", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Ending activity

```
private void endActivity() {
    //Back to Maps Activity
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        success = problemPicture.delete();
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No picture found");
    }
    if(success) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Picture deleted");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Picture could not be deleted");
    }

    success = deleteFile("problemPicture.png");
    if(success) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File deleted");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "File could not be deleted");
    }

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OS Finalizada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent it = new Intent(StatusActivity.this, MapsActivity.class)
            .putExtra("index", index);
    startActivity(it);
}
```

Sorry for the wall of bad code, and thank you!

Comment: show your code we can help you!

Comment: To do this, I think you'd have to build the email-sending directly into your app.  Even if you could pass an attachment "in memory" (or delete the file on "disk" after it's been sent), using an email intent will launch whichever email program is on the user's phone, most of which will retain copies of sent emails.

Comment: @PedroCunial see below answer and comment below if have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

As for sharing image, we send URI of the image through the intent to the corresponding application. There is no possible way to send it without using URI. And URI requires that the image must be saved. So there is no possibility. If you have a problem of deleting it after share .... better save in [DiskCache](https://developer.android.com/samples/DisplayingBitmaps/src/com.example.android.displayingbitmaps/util/DiskLruCache.html), so that it automatically gets deleted on the basis of LRU.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;

    public void takePhoto(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case TAKE_PICTURE:
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
//                      ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_comment);
//                      image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        // set image if you want to

                        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                uri);
                        shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,
                                "choose one"));
                        // your desired intent with your own parames subject and others 
                        // no need to del and others.
                        // this is test in API 19 hope it will work for you too!

                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```